# Can radio waves be stored in a device for future use?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

Is it possible to store  electromagnetic waves consisting of radio waves only without any other intermittent signals??

Comment: Do you mean to store the actual radio waves? And, what are "other intermittent signals"?

Comment: What do you mean?  Do you mean, for example, capturing the transmission from a radio station, storing it, and releasing it at some future time so that a radio receiver can "hear" it?   All of this without resorting to storage in a computer memory or a recording medium like a disk, I presume.

Comment: **yes**, according to [Light self-trapping in a large cloud of cold atoms](http://arxiv.org/abs/1104.1916) . The same author  worked on slowed light intented to store data ( in the circuitry during the transport ) [Phase conjugation and slow light in dye-doped chiral nematics](https://www.osapublishing.org/ol/abstract.cfm?uri=ol-37-22-4684)

Answer (score 4):

Every radio wave is "stored" in space between the time it is sent and the time it is received. You could prolong that time by send the wave into a long, low-loss waveguide. In reality waveguides do have some associated losses so it would only be a short term solution, but any RF delay line is in essence a short term RF storage device.

Comment: Or record it. Bounce it back and forth off the moon.

Comment: @JonCuster hey, you've just invented the resonant cavity.  :-). Now you just need a 100.00000000000% reflective moon.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - nah, just upconvert to the visible and bounce off the Apollo mirrors, then send through an amplifier down here for each pass... Here on Earth, a microsecond of storage is under 1000 feet of coax.Even easier would be to just record the darn thing...

Comment: I assume that "without any intermittent signals" intended to say "without converting to another signal form" - eliminating either the "convert to light" or "record it" suggestions. And if you have a resonant cavity you don't really preserve the modulation of your signal. You can't store FM (obviously) or even AM signals in a sufficiently high Q resonant cavity and replay them - at best you could store the energy. Briefly. With low enough Q you have just a component of your RF transmitter/receiver...

Answer (score 1):

Speaking more generally, waves of any kind are just a physical expression of the flow of energy through time and space. And energy can be 'stored' by either converting it to another form (for example electrical to chemical as in a battery) or by trapping it within a confined space using resonance, such as in the wave guide Floris suggested.